# Not Displaying Nape Body

Tags: actionscript-3, class, oop, flashdevelop

I had these two in the same Main class. Now there are Main.as and MainChar.as

When compiling doesn't show any errors but it isn't displaying the object either :c

It is the first time I am splitting code into different classes. I just figured what should be in the hero creation class and what should stay in Main.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import nape.geom.Vec2;
    import nape.phys.Body;
    import nape.phys.BodyList;
    import nape.space.Space;

    import MainChar;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        public var gravity:Number = 600;
        public var space:Space = new Space(new Vec2(0, gravity));   
        public var hero:MainChar = new MainChar();

        public function Main():void
        {
            hero.createMainCharacter(stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2, 50, 50);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
        }

        private function update(e:Event):void 
        {
            space.step(1 / stage.frameRate, 10, 10);
            var bodies:BodyList = space.bodies;
            for (var i:int = 0; i < bodies.length; i++) 
            {
                var body:Body=bodies.at(i);
                if (body.userData.sprite != null) 
                {
                    body.userData.sprite.x = body.position.x;
                    body.userData.sprite.y = body.position.y;
                    body.userData.sprite.rotation=(body.rotation*180/Math.PI)%360;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hero creator class:

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import nape.geom.Vec2;
    import nape.phys.Body;
    import nape.phys.BodyType;
    import nape.shape.Polygon;
    import nape.space.Space;

    public class MainChar extends Sprite
    {
        public var space:Space = new Space(new Vec2(0, 600));

        public function MainChar():void 
        {
        } 

        public function createMainCharacter(x:Number, y:Number, width:Number, height:Number):void 
        {
            var mainChar:Body = new Body(BodyType.DYNAMIC);
            var mainCharShape:Polygon = new Polygon(Polygon.box(width, height));

            mainChar.shapes.add(mainCharShape);
            mainChar.position.setxy(x, y);
            mainChar.space = space;

            var mainCharSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
                mainCharSprite.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
                mainCharSprite.graphics.drawRect( -width/2, -height/2, width, height);
                mainCharSprite.graphics.endFill;
            addChild(mainCharSprite);

            mainChar.userData.sprite = mainCharSprite;
            addChild(mainChar.userData.sprite);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I added the constructor function - Although without anything in it. `public function MainChar():void{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your `hero` as a child of your `Main` sprite EG:

```
  public function Main():void
  {
        hero.createMainCharacter(stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2, 50, 50);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
        addChild(hero);
  }
```

Comment: The body is at the top left corner and stays there, it should spawn at middle of the screen `hero.createMainCharacter(stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2, 50, 50);` and it should fall `public var space:Space = new Space(new Vec2(0, 600));`

Comment: That would usually indicate that your `Main` has not had it's height and width set correctly

Comment: I think the sprite is not sticking to the body.

Comment: I added the `for (var i:int = 0; i < bodies.length; i++)` loop to the MainChar class in an update function and the body went to its place. Although not falling. Going to fiddle with the space vec now I guess

Comment: --" `space.step(1 / stage.frameRate, 10, 10);` added this line to MainChar class instead of Main and it worked. Shouldn't those two, the for loop and step, be in Main?

Comment: Maybe these `Space` and `Body` objects are not being stored in the vector correctly? I'm not really familiar with your `Space` or `Body` Classes, so I can't really say. If your having a new issues I would suggest raising it as a new question, since comments are intended for discussing the posted question/answer as posted.